# How to reload list when delete item from it in flutter

Tags: android, ios, list, flutter, dart

I want when I click on trash can icon to delete this item from list and reload it.

how can do this in `listview.builder` ??

[image]

Comment: consider adding more code so we can see what you've done so far. For instance, the answers so far are guessing if you're using setState or provider, but you could make that clearer for them

Answer (score 0):

Flutter automatically updates changes to datasources. This is only applied after calling

setState((){
});

or using Provider and calling  `notifyListeners();`
So that should be run after you delete the item from the list.